# Do you need to update the data when it doesn't change

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I want to update a row in the table，before updating, do I need to check if there is any change in each column?

Comment: That's entirely up to you.

Comment: A table has _rows_, not records, and _columns_, not fields.

Comment: I believe that if MySQL detects that a record would not change at all from an update statement, then it won't even touch that record (FYI).

Comment: @jarlh As you said, I will reedit the problem

Comment: @JohnConde If the data does not change, have I executed a useless sql?

Comment: @jarlh There is no problem with that. A [*row*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_(database)) is also called a *record* and [*column*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_(database)) a *field*.

Comment: @revo, According to the ISO/ANSI SQL specification there are _rows_ and _columns_. (A _field_ is either a part of a datetime value, or a part of a record data type.)

Comment: @jarlh I appreciate what ever you learnt from standards but it doesn't mean they are not interchangeable as they are, normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySQL, you do not need to check the value.  MySQL does not update the record if there is no change.  That means that MySQL does not incur the overhead of logging or writing the data.  There is a slight cost of checking if any values changed, and I think it does run the triggers.

Other databases behave differently.

This is in an arcane location in the documentation, where [`mysql_affected_rows()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) is described:

> For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the
>   number of rows actually changed.
>
> . . .
>
> An integer greater than zero indicates the number of rows affected or
>   retrieved. Zero indicates that no records were updated for an UPDATE
>   statement, no rows matched the WHERE clause in the query or that no
>   query has yet been executed.

Comment: *`create_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP* I have a colum of settings like this, I found that this value will change

Comment: @Frank.Dai . . . Then that answers your question.  A column changes.

Comment: Can you help me find mysql official documentation on this part?I did not find it.

Comment: @Frank.Dai . . . I'm actually glad that you asked.  I had looked for the documentation earlier and didn't remember where it was.  But I have included the relevant part in the answer.

Comment: Presumably this means that BEFORE/AFTER UPDATE triggers don't fire if the row meets the WHERE clause (or there is no WHERE clause) but the UPDATE wouldn't change that row's data?

Answer (score 0):

That would be totally up to you to check if anything is in there before hand. You can do updates based on a single row, multiple, or all of them.

An example where you update a specific row is like this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET Username='TestName123'
WHERE UserID='12486';
```

where you would be changing the username where the userid is 12486

OR you can update all of the rows with data you want like

```
UPDATE Customers
SET Country='USA'
```

This would update every record to have the Country column be filled with USA.

Answer (score 0):

mysql appears to not update the actual row if no data changed.

Demonstration:

```
create temporary table test (id int not null, value int default null, PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
insert into test (id, value) values (1,1),(2,2);

-- no-change update
update test set value = 2 where id = 2;
select row_count();
> "mysql -vvv" rows_affected output: Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
> mysql output: Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
> row_count: 0

-- has-change update
update test set value = 3 where id = 2;
select row_count();
> "mysql -vvv" rows_affected output: Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
> mysql output: Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> row_count: 1

I believe: row_count = rows_affected = "Changed"
```

The mysql_rows_affected link is helpful but does not explicitly state that the row will not be updated if there is no data change. It only states that the row will not be updated if it does not match the UPDATE's WHERE-clause.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html

Note that I don't see any documented guarantee of this behaviour (that mysql will never write rows if the data has not changed).